# Highcharts Waterfall graph using a column graph

Tags: highcharts, waterfall

I would like to create a Waterfall graph using Highcharts, but I would like to use a COLUMN type graph, as I need custom tooltips shown on the sum and intermediate sum columns.

The question is: 
How can I create a COLUMN graph where I define both the Y-start and the Y-end value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use object notation for points:

```
series: [{
   data: [{
       y: 20,
       low: 10
   }]
}]
```

Comment: Columnrange is an another option. You said you want to use COLUMN chart ;)